# Airplay glitches every once in a while on LG tv

Tags: audio, video, airplay, streaming

I have an LG CX at home, which has built in Airplay 2 which is great. The issue is that every second or third time I try to play something over Airplay from my MBP the video and audio glitches consistently.

The WiFi connection is not a problem, neither is the source of the stream (since there is no problem when the stream is on the MBP screen).

Is there anything I can do to resolve this? How can I troubleshoot?

Comment: I bet the problems occur when you are streaming video (Netflix, Youtube, etc) for the LG from your laptop, and **does not happen** when you are showing non-streaming content. Where I work, we discourage the use of AirPlay from laptops to broadcast streams to AirPlay devices (AppleTVs connected to a projectors) because it just hammers the WiFi performance at the laptop end, resulting in audio and video glitches. Tests with AppleTVs connected by wire (ethernet) have no such problems. Since the projectors are also hard-wired with HDMI, a cabled connection is recommended for this purpose.

Comment: @IconDaemon I tried connecting the TV via cable, that didn't alleviate the problem. I will try to do the same with an old mac mini which has AirServer installed